# If the limit of product of two sequences and limit of one of those two sequences are given, find the limit of the other sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

I was trying to prove the following :

Let $(x_n),(y_n)$ be two bounded sequences with $\lim_{n\to\infty} x_n y_n =a, \lim_{n\to\infty} x_n =b \neq 0,$ then $\lim_{n\to\infty} y_n =\frac{a}{b}.$

**Proof** :
Since $(y_n)$ is bounded, there exists a real number $M$ such that $|y_n|\leq M.$
Also,
$\lim_{n\to\infty} x_n =b \implies |x_n-b| \rightarrow{0},$ as $n \rightarrow{\infty}$
&  $\lim_{n\to\infty} x_ny_n =a \implies |x_ny_n-a| \rightarrow{0},$ as $n \rightarrow{\infty}$
Now, we consider
\begin{align*}
&\hspace{0.5cm} |y_n-\frac{a}{b}|\\
& =\frac{1}{|b|}|by_n-a|\\
& =\frac{1}{|b|}|by_n-x_ny_n+x_ny_n-a|\\
& \leq \frac{1}{|b|}\{|by_n-x_ny_n|+|x_ny_n-a|\}\\
& \leq \frac{1}{|b|}\{|b-x_n||y_n|+|x_ny_n-a|\}\\
& \leq \frac{M}{|b|}|b-x_n|+\frac{1}{|b|}|x_ny_n-a|\\
& \rightarrow{\frac{M}{|b|}\times 0}+\frac{1}{b} \times 0\\
& =0
\end{align*}
Thus, $|y_n-\frac{a}{b}| \rightarrow{0}$ as $n \rightarrow{\infty}.$
As a result, $\lim_{n\to\infty} y_n =\frac{a}{b}.$

Please check the solution and let me know if there is any mistake. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yeah, seems fine

Comment: @user490489 I don't know why go through all this trouble. By the algebraic properties of limits $\lim y_n =\lim x_ny_n \frac{1}{x_n}$$=\lim x_ny_n \lim \frac{1}{x_n}=\frac{a}{b}$.

Comment: @user490489 as a matter of fact, the assumption that $(y_n)$ is bounded can be dropped. Also, the boundedness of $(x_n)$ follows from its convergence.